# Secure INSERTs with MySQLi

Tags: php, security, mysqli

Is this code well protected, and if not, could you tell me how it might be exploited and how to secure it?

```
if(isset($_POST['vrsta_predmeta']) AND !empty($_POST['vrsta_predmeta']) AND 

isset($_POST['res_text']) AND isset($_POST['glavni_dug']) AND isset($_POST['res']) AND isset($_POST['zaklj']) AND isset($_POST['povjerilac']) AND isset($_POST['duznik']) AND isset($_POST['predmet_zaveden'])){


$racunob =  trim($_POST['rac']);
$obrazlozenje = trim($_POST['obr']);     
$ob_text = trim($_POST['res_ob']);  
$res_text = trim($_POST['res_text']);
$vrsta_pre = trim($_POST['vrsta_predmeta']);
$izvrsenje = trim(strtolower($_POST['res']));
$obrazac = trim($_POST['zaklj']);
$povjerilac = $_POST['povjerilac'];
$duznik = $_POST['duznik'];
$datum= trim($_POST['predmet_zaveden']);
 foreach($povjerilac as $key){
 $lica = $db -> prepare("INSERT INTO p_lica(povjerilac, doc_br, dokument_vlasnik) VALUES('$key', '$dok_broj', '$ses_val')");



}       


foreach($duznik as $key1){
 $lica1 = $db -> prepare("INSERT INTO d_lica(duznik,doc_br, dokument_vlasnik) VALUES('$key1', '$dok_broj', '$ses_val')");


}

$insert_dok = $db -> prepare("INSERT INTO document_tbl(dokument_vlasnik,dokument_broj,vrsta_dokumenta,zakljucak, resenje_izvrsenja,datum,resenje_text,obrazlozenje,obtext,racunob) VALUES('$ses_val','$dok_broj', '$vrsta_pre','$obrazac','$izvrsenje','$datum','$res_text','$obrazlozenje','$ob_text','$racunob')");
if($lica -> execute() AND $insert_dok -> execute() AND $lica1 -> execute()){


   $lica -> close();
   $lica1 -> close();
   $insert_dok -> close();


  echo '<script>new Messi(\'Dokument uspjesno dodat.\', {title: \'Obavjestenje\', titleClass: \'success\', buttons: [{id: 0, label: \'Close\', val: \'X\'}]});</script>';
header('location:login.php');
  }else{
   echo '<script>new Messi(\'Dokument uspjesno dodat.\', {title: \'Obavjestenje\', titleClass: \'anim warning\', buttons: [{id: 0, label: \'Close\', val: \'X\'}]});</script>'; 
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, this code is not secure, as you are using prepared statements wrong. See here for [correct usage of mysqli prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) (you should not ever have user supplied input in the `prepare` statement, it is only for SQL syntax; add the user input via `bind` later on).

For example, your code might look like this:

```
$sql = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO p_lica (povjerilac, doc_br, dokument_vlasnik) VALUES(?, ?, ?)'); // note that there is no user input in prepare
$sql->bind_param('iss', $key, $dok_broj, $ses_val); // s for string, i for integer. use d for double, b for blob

foreach($povjerilac as $key) { // set values for $key, which is bound to the first ? parameter     
    $sql->execute(); // insert new row with current key
}
$sql->close();
```

(see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488033/php-mysqli-multiple-inserts) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15149157/best-way-to-insert-many-values-in-mysqli))

**Misc**

- formatting: your code is very badly formatted. If this is just a copy-paste error it's ok, but otherwise, you should definitely fix it.
- variable names: the standard is to use english names, if you can.
- your header call seems wrong. From the documentation: `Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent`. You should also use a complete URL.

Comment: Ok, thanks for response. If I won't use bind_param how then code should look like?

Comment: @Vladimir: Like a blank sheet of paper: if you're not going to use prepared statements, then don't `INSERT` user data. Use prepared statements or don't query. Full stop.

Comment: @Vladimir why wouldn't you use bind_param? You should. I added an example.

Comment: I tought it's secured also without using bind_param. Shuold I use bind_param for all variables or I can use just for few? Also sould I use bind_param with select and update or what?

Comment: @Vladimir like I said in my answer, *you shouldn't ever have user input in `prepare`*. With that in mind, you don't have all that many other options. And you should use bind for all variables, and also for select and update.

Answer (score 2):

Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to secure your SQL, it's built in the default PHP and work with 12 database types. it also makes it a lot easier when it comes to making prepared statements.

**PDO:**

```
$params = array(
    ':username' => 'test', 
    ':email' => $mail, 
    ':last_login' => time() - 3600
);

$pdo->prepare('
    SELECT * FROM users
    WHERE username = :username
    AND email = :email
    AND last_login > :last_login');

$pdo->execute($params);
```

**MySQLi:**

```
$query = $mysqli->prepare('
    SELECT * FROM users
    WHERE username = ?
    AND email = ?
    AND last_login > ?');

$query->bind_param('sss', 'test', $mail, time() - 3600);
$query->execute();
```

As you can see, A big bonus is that you can use `:name` instead of `?`

---

Here some tutorial about PDO

[W3Schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)
[Tuts+ Tutorial (Recommended)](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059)